# Extra plugins in child pom which are not inherited

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I know the concept of super pom and inheritance. But still I see extra plugins magically coming up in my child module effective pom.

The project is very simple :

[image]

We have 2 POM -one for parent module and one for child module.

Parent module :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.practice</groupId>
  <artifactId>learning-maven</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>child-module1</module>
  </modules>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>


    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>fr.jcgay.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>buildplan-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>


  </build>
</project>
```

Child module POM :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.practice</groupId>
        <artifactId>learning-maven</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>child-module1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

</project>
```

If I generate effective POM of child and parent module I get this :
(I am showing the effective POM data of plugins and goals through [buildplan-maven-plugin](http://buildplan.jcgay.fr/) for ease of reading. I have checked these plugin data with respect to effective POM too.)

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building learning-maven 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- buildplan-maven-plugin:1.3:list (default-cli) @ learning-maven ---
[INFO] Build Plan for learning-maven: 
----------------------------------------------------------
PLUGIN               | PHASE   | ID              | GOAL   
----------------------------------------------------------
maven-install-plugin | install | default-install | install
maven-deploy-plugin  | deploy  | default-deploy  | deploy 
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building child-module1 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- buildplan-maven-plugin:1.3:list (default-cli) @ child-module1 ---
[INFO] Build Plan for child-module1: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PLUGIN                 | PHASE                  | ID                    | GOAL         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
maven-resources-plugin | process-resources      | default-resources     | resources    
maven-compiler-plugin  | compile                | default-compile       | compile      
maven-resources-plugin | process-test-resources | default-testResources | testResources
maven-compiler-plugin  | test-compile           | default-testCompile   | testCompile  
maven-surefire-plugin  | test                   | default-test          | test         
maven-jar-plugin       | package                | default-jar           | jar          
maven-install-plugin   | install                | default-install       | install      
maven-deploy-plugin    | deploy                 | default-deploy        | deploy       
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you see in child module , you are getting more plugins than the parent.
If you want to see the super POM , it is [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html).
So where does this extra plugins coming from in child module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see it in your child pom, but you probably set the packaging to `jar` somewhere. The standard lifecycle of Maven defines several goals to be called depending on the packaging, and the Maven plugins you list would fit well to those goals.

Comment: Absolutely correct. If `<packaging>` not mentioned , then by default it is jar.

Comment: My mistake: I usually know that packaging is not inherited, but I was probably too tired...